# Can't access res.statusMessage in Javascript async/await try/catch client code to read exception thrown from express backend

Tags: javascript, exception, axios, http-status-codes, status-message

[image]

Chrome can read the message provided by the server `(No project found for 70100)` but when I `console.log(err.message)` I just get `Request failed with status code 400`

Client code:

```
const doFetch = async () => {
      try {
          const {data} = await axios.post('/docs/query/project', {projectId: '70100'});
          console.log(data);
          setFetched(data);

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    }
```

Server code:

```
try {
        const docs = await docsDb.getProject(projectId);
        res.json(docs);
    } catch(err) {
        res.statusMessage = `No project found for ${projectId}`;
        res.status(400).end();
    }
```

It's annoying that Chrome can read my message, but I can't figure out how to display it to the user. Obviously the message is getting as far as the browser, I would appreciate some tips on how to access it in my client code! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inspect the ‘err’- object, it likely has ‘err.response’ set. More info: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md#handling-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `statusMessage` sent in the node response surfaces in the Axios response as a `statusText` property. You can see the response object associated with a failed request by looking at the `err.response` property of an Axios error. Be careful, though; if no  HTTP request was issued because the error relates to things like connection failures, `err.response` won't exist.

```
const doFetch = async () => {
  try {
    const {data} = await axios.post('/docs/query/project', {projectId: '70100'});
    setFetched(data);
  } catch (err) {
    const message = err.response
      ? `Request failed with ${err.response.status}: ${err.response.statusText}`
      : err.message;
    console.error(message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`err.response.statusText` on the client contains the text set in `res.statusMessage` on the server.

Live and learn

Comment: _"Live and learn"_  you'll get further by reading the documentation and learning